# Do you know a better way to create filter like [1,0,0,1,0,...]

Tags: python, filter, zip, nonetype

I have a list of lists with same length, for example

```
[
    [23,12,23,1,32,None,12,None],
    [None,456,2,None,4,545,56,12],
    [435,None,4,3,None,44,12,23]
]
```

Now I want to create a final pattern like:

`[0,0,1,1,0,1,0]` --> like zipping all 3 lists and setting `0 if None else 1`

I got a solution for that but I think it can be done easier

```
filter_by_nones = [1] * len(lists_for_filtering[0])
for list_of_values in lists_for_filtering:
    temp_pattern = []
    [temp_pattern.append(1) if value is not None else temp_pattern.append(0)
     for value in list_of_values]
    filter_by_nones = [a * b for a, b in zip(temp_pattern, filter_by_nones)]
```

I think about using the python filter function somehow for that --> iterating takes to long time when there is a list including 10 lists with 1million+ values in each list

Comment: that's really simple with a library like `numpy`. Any restrictions on using it?

Comment: in the end it should be a python list.
so using  .tolist() in the end is ok

Comment: Have you looked into `itertools.compress()`?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use NumPy, you can use `all` and list comprehension. The `zip` will group the elements index-wise and then `all` will be `True` if no element is `None` and vice versa

```
lst = [[23,12,23,1,32,None,12,None],
       [None,456,2,None,4,545,56,12],
       [435,None,4,3,None,44,12,23] ]

answer = [int(all(sub)) for sub in zip(*lst)]
# [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

**NumPy solution**: `lst==None` will give a matrix of `True` and `False`. Then sum them (OR operation) row wise and then subtract from 1 to get the final answer.

```
lst = np.array([[23,12,23,1,32,None,12,None],
                [None,456,2,None,4,545,56,12],
                [435,None,4,3,None,44,12,23] ])

answer = 1-(lst==None).sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: `all(sub)` you mean

Comment: It also removes the integer 0.
how to make it only to remove only None's?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use numpy, you could do

```
x =    [[23,12,23,1,32,None,12,None],
       [None,456,2,None,4,545,56,12],
       [435,None,4,3,None,44,12,23] ]
mask  = np.where(np.logical_and.reduce(x) != None , 1 , 0)
```